# How to use Palladio font in text body but Computer Modern for Equations?

Tags: fonts

i want my text body to be set in a Palladio-like font, but my equations to be set in Computer Modern.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}  

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=x^2 \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(2\pi f_0 t)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

What should i do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: That seems a strange setup: Computer Modern math fonts are largely visually incompatible with Palladio/Palatino.

Comment: Maybe i identified the fonts in the document i want to replicate wrong. See follow up questeion https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492591/what-fonts-are-used-in-this-book

Comment: If you want to use an up-to-date Palatino text font, you should really also go for an up-to-date Palatino math font. The `mathpazo` package is beyond ancient. Do consider loading the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` font packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't load the `mathpazo` package. Instead, load the `newpxtext` package. As the name of the package indicates, it provides only text fonts, no math fonts.

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\linespread{1.05}  

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=x^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(2\pi f_0 t)\,dt
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just rename the default family name:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplj}

\linespread{1.05}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Abcdef}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=x^2 \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(2\pi f_0 t)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The output of `pdffonts` is

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
DZRMSF+URWPalladioL-Roma             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
CXJMMY+TeXPalladioL-SC               Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
NMBJYD+CMMI12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
VRSLZY+CMR12                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       7  0
VOPKHO+CMR8                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       8  0
CKUQXN+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       9  0
UYVLXV+CMEX10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      10  0
BECFBN+CMSY8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      11  0
```

[image]

With `pplx` instead of `pplj` you get “uppercase digits” and true small caps (thanks to Ralf Steubner for suggesting it).

[image]

The output of `pdffonts`

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
DKRBIK+URWPalladioL-Roma             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
GDZRLO+TeXPalladioL-SC               Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
NMBJYD+CMMI12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
VRSLZY+CMR12                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       7  0
VOPKHO+CMR8                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       8  0
CKUQXN+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       9  0
UYVLXV+CMEX10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      10  0
BECFBN+CMSY8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      11  0
```

The output is bad in either case, as Palatino/Palladio is visually incompatible with Computer Modern.

Comment: +1 for "The output is bad in either case, as Palatino/Palladio is visually incompatible with Computer Modern."

Comment: @Mico +1 also for me. It is absolutely true that the fonts are not compatible, but the retina monitor of the MaC of egreg is simply fantastic :-) that makes fonts look like they fit perfectly.

Comment: I dont quite get it. Could you two elaborate on 'visually incompatible'? What do you mean by that and then why does some books use this setup?

Comment: You can use `pplx` to get real small caps together with lining figures.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks for the suggestion!